# calculating numerical integral in c++

Tags: c++

I want to write a function that can calculate me inetegral `e^(cos x)` on range (a,b)

```
double integral(double(*f)(double x), double a, double b, int n) {
    double step = (b - a) / n;  // width of each small rectangle
    double area = 0.0;  // signed area
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
        area += f(a + (i + 0.5) * step) * step; // sum up each small rectangle
    }
    return area;
}
```

This is what I have found but I`m new in c++ and I can't work with pointers 
if there is another way please help me.

Comment: A) I take it this isn't your code? B) What do you mean "I cant work with pointers"?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I have to do this without pointers

Comment: If you can't use function pointers, then you should use `std::function`. Those are the two ways to pass a function to another function in C++.

Comment: The problem is i have to calculate integral without pointers

Comment: Are you allowed to use templates?

Comment: No .i can not write it with templates too

Comment: Do you have to pass the integral function in? Or is it always the one above? Because you could just call the function directly instead of having a pointer to it in that case.

Comment: Are you trying to make a *generic* integral function without pointers or are you trying to make a non-generic dedicated function to calculate the integral of your specific function and nothing else?

Comment: @Amir5204 -- You say you're new to C++, but are an authority on what you can't use.  Why not list everything you can't use, so that persons trying to help you don't wind up wasting time giving you answers.  Otherwise what you posted, is more or less, how you integrate in C++.  A function `f(x)` is passed to the integration function, and the integration function does whatever it does to return the result.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie *cough* sounds like homework *cough*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function you found allows you to integrate any function you want, and that funcion is the first parameter of the integral method. You can just remove the first argument ('double(*f)(double x)' ), that is because the function you want to integrate is known ( e^cos(x)), so you don't need to give it as an argument. Then, in the for loop, you just replace de f function for e^cos(x). The method will look like this:

```
double integral(double a, double b, int n){
    double step = (b - a) / n;  // width of each small rectangle
    double area = 0.0;  // signed area
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
        area += exp(cos(a + (i + 0.5) * step)) * step; // sum up each small rectangle
    }
    return area;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
T integral(const std::function<T(T)>& f, T a, T b, int n) {
    auto step = (b - a) / n;  // width of each small rectangle
    auto area = static_cast<T>(0);  // signed area
    for (auto i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        // sum up each small rectangle
        area += f(a + (i + static_cast<T>( 0.5)) * step) * step; 
    }
    return area;
}

int main()
{
    std::function<float(float)> f_sine =  [](float in) { return sin(in); };
    auto two = integral(f_sine, 0.0f, 3.14f, 20);
    return 0;
}
```

That will be $3.50

Comment: `No .i can not write it with templates too – Amir5204 15 mins ago` No dollars for you.

Comment: @Borgleader i did it for the charma